# Angular 5 - Routing to the same component with different URL's

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I have the following routes which should route to the same component, I can get it to work by using this following structure.

```
const carModuleRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'car/:category/:carId', component: CarDetailComponent},
    { path: 'car/:carId', component: CarDetailComponent},
];
```

But I know this is not a standard way to do so, Is there a proper way of doing the same functionality ?

Comment: Why ? It's ok like that.

Comment: `redirectTo` can help you?

Comment: So its fine to use it like that ?

Comment: I do not think it's good practice. Becouse the same resource can have 2 URLs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the standard way of defining `routes` and their respective `components`. You are inside `routing` module and you are trying to define `routes`, and not the `components`.

So, do not overlook to group the same `component` and define `routes` for them. What you have done seems appropriate.

EDIT :

Your case is very simple, you can simply do :

```
const carModuleRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'car/:category/:carId', redirectTo : 'car/:carId', pathMatch : 'full'},
    { path: 'car/:carId', component: CarDetailComponent},
];
```

Note :

In this case, your url will change and you might loose the value of `:category`, which might have been useful in the component. So it is best to specify multiple routes pointing to same component as a seperate case.

Answer (score 3):

its ok to use also you can use redirect and child routing for same component. You have done it right way .

[Refrence:https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html)

[Child Routing REF : https://angular.io/guide/router#child-routing-component](https://angular.io/guide/router#child-routing-component)

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue where I need to navigate to a different route using the same component using the following approach:

```
/* My Grid route: */
const GridRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'grid',
        component: BasicLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: ListItemComponent
            },
            {
                path : 'view-files/:id',
                component : ListItemComponent
            },
            {
                path : 'filter',
                component: ListItemComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];

@Component({
  templateUrl: './list-item.component.html',
})
export class ListItemComponent {

   ...
   ...

    /* Function to navigate */
    navigateToRoute(path: string) {
       this.router.navigate([ path ]);
    }
}
```

Then, call the navigate function on the template (`list-item.component.html`).

```
<a (click)="navigateToRoute('page/edit/' + dataItem.id)">Link</a>
```

Hope that help!